# AWS EBS snapshot, is there a way to know if the EBS is currently being written to

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am making a snap shot util so I can take snap shots of any ebs. The snapshots are recommended to take place while the EBS is not active(by AWS), because if it is active while you take a snapshot, it won't pick up anything that is being written at the time of the snapshot.

I was wondering if there is a way to determine if the EBS is being written to, or any ideas of how to determine such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The concern is whether or not the volume is being written to when the snapshot is initiated. From outside of the instance, you will not be able to tell, unless the attached instance is stopped or its not attached at all.

From within the instance, you can freeze the filesystem to make it consistent. You don't need to freeze it for the entire duration of creating a snapshot, just initiating it.

Comment: I don't know what file systems the end user might be using, lets say not all of them can 'freeze' the instance. Is it going to be up to the user to 'stop' all activity or 'writes' and then run my snapshot script, or is there some type of precaution I can take for ALL file systems to have some sort of 'freeze' implemented. I am leaning towards just doing hot snapshots, and hoping these snapshots are taken when no one is active or something.

Comment: On linux most file systems can be frozen. The command may vary depending on the filesystem used. I don't know if the same can be said about windows however.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a method to freeze or otherwise quiesce the application, the only way to ensure the volume is not written to is either to stop the instance or to dismount the volume, both mean some downtime in the application, which may not be acceptable.
You have many ways to make sure the snapshots are consistent: you can do the quiescing on the application level and not the filesystem level (e.g. MySQL) to ensure all files are closed.
You may also want to take a look at my company's product, [Cloud Protection Manager](http://n2ws.com), a full-featured EC2 backup & recovery solution, based on EBS snapshots, that supports application-consistent backup.